# If Else statement jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, each

What I want to do:

When there is only one `.bx-pager-item` in `.bx-pager`, I want to hide `.bx-pager`. 
When there are more, I want to show `.bx-pager`

I've written this shorthand function:

```
var n = $(".bx-pager-item").length;
$(".bx-pager").css("display", (n < 2) ? "none" : "block");
```

This works fine when there's only one `.bx-pager` on my page, but I want to add more. When I do that it doesn't work anymore. Any suggestions?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGs4t/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all the `.bx-pager` elements and check for the number of `.bx-pager-item` elements within each iteration.

```
$('.bx-pager').each(function() {
    $(this).css("display", $(".bx-pager-item", this).length < 2 ? "none" : "block");
});
```

[**Update fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rGs4t/3/)

Answer (score 0):

use `.each` in your code:

```
$('.bx-pager').each(function() {
    var count = $(".bx-pager-item", this).length;
    $(this).css("display", (count < 2) ? "none" : "block");
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/SCHYq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/rGs4t/1/

Using an each on the pagers will do this for you.

JS:

```
$(".bx-pager").each(function (index, pager) {
    var n = $(".bx-pager-item", pager).length;
    $(pager).css("display", (n < 2) ? "none" : "block");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.bx-pager').each(function () {
    $(this)[($('.bx-pager-item', this).length < 2) ? 'hide' : 'show']();
});
```